# Cannot get Dell Wireless WLAN 1397 Minicard to work

Tags: 10.10, wireless, networking

I am not sure if this is the right place for this question, but I currently am running Ubuntu 10.10 and have windows installed with the dual boot option. My wireless card is the Dell Wireless WLAN 1397 Minicard. When running Windows, it detects and connects to all the available wireless networks that I have access to. However, when i boot into Ubuntu, it connects to the wireless networks only sometimes, other time ,on entering the username and passphrase, it tries to connect for about a minute and then fails to do so. I read the following on a forum as a temporary fix:

I Should turn the system off, remove the battery, reconnect and turn it on again.

This always works, but it really inconvenient and sometimes, looses connectivy after about 5 minutes of having connected. I would like to point out that it worked fine when I was running Ubuntu 10.04

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: As it happens, this isn't the right place (sorry!). This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 2):

Try the latest drivers for this 1397 driver. I remember this driver is a non free one. You can find updates or new non-free drivers from Additional Drivers application which can be found under System -> Preferences

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned.I have tried both the drivers available under the addition drivers application. Neither of them work.

Comment: Also tried some of the info given here http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1352270
 That did not work either.

Comment: if you have done an upgrde, may be that has broken it. try creating a test profile and see if you get any different result than your existing login.

Comment: This did not seem to help. Same issue.